# Keeping a button and text field horizontally level inside a table cell in HTML

Tags: html, css, button, input, html-table

I am trying to have a table where inside the cells of the left most columns there is both a button defined by the `<input>` tag and a text field defined by the `<td>` tag. More specifically, below is the actual html for each row in the table.

```
<td width="10%" ><input  style = "font-size: 12px;"  type="submit" name="expand" value="+"/>{$SPName}</td>
```

My problem is when the text field is longer than the cell can hold, the button ends up above the text field. What I want is for the button to always be to the left of the text, no matter how long the text. The overflowing text can wrap around below the button and first part of the text. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css property `'white-space:nowrap'` on the table cell.

```
<td width="10%" style="white-space:nowrap"><input  style = "font-size: 12px;"  type="submit" name="expand" value="+"/>{$SPName}</td>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! I really appreciate it. That helped solve the problem but my table has many columns so I don't know if thats the perfect solution in the long run... Do you know if there is any way to get the text to still wrap, but will keep the button and the first part of the text on the same line??

Answer (score 0):

I used a word break which lets it break after any character. I'm not 100% sure this is what you were asking for but I believe it may at least help.

```css
div.test {
    width: 11em; 
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"><td width="10%"><input style = "font-size: 12px;" type="submit" name="expand" value="+"/>{$SPName}</td></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem remained the same even with these additions. I appreciate the help though!